# How should I handle HEAD requests for large files in node.js?

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

Using my own node.js server I want to get the size of a large file (> 4gB) before making byte range requests on it. If, upon receiving a HEAD request, I use fs.readFile I get "RangeError: File size is greater than possible Buffer" errors; if I use fs.createReadStream I don't get that error but then I don't know how to respond to the request. For one thing, I don't see how to get the file size from the stream; for another, I don't how to fill out the response header even if I knew the file size. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `fs.stat` would suffice. Also, you need to look for documentation regarding HTTP HEAD requests. Try looking for the RFC document on it.